# Override two images with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to override two images on top of other using Bootstrap, as the code below:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2" style="border:solid 1px black">
            <div style='position: relative; width:100%; height:100%; background:center; border:solid 1px red'>
                <img src="Images/banner-transparente.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
                <div style='position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 20%; border:solid 1px black'>
                    <img src="Images/logo-trt-home.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is OK when the screen is in a large scale:

[image: its-work]

but when on small screens, the image is cropped.

[image: doesnt-work]

How can I do that using Bootstrap's grid system, using the responsiveness needed for the image?

code on http://jsfiddle.net/s116Ld99/5/

Comment: are you using img-responsive class for image ?

Comment: would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: Please, post your jsfiddle

Comment: sorry guys! my bad about code. done!

Comment: I'm newbie about bootstrap. I'm tried use img-responsive, but not sure if I do this correctly.

Comment: @Fulvius Jsfiddle makes easier to understand your problem and solve it.

Comment: First, I don't think all your inline-css are needed, it usually works as it is. The fastest solution is probably to "inspect the element" (left-click or F12) and "uncheck" the css properties until you understand the problem. If that doesn't work, try to change stuff, begin with things like `position`, `float` and `height`.

Comment: @alirezasafian http://jsfiddle.net/s116Ld99/5/  Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the code below:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2" style="border:solid 1px black">
            <div style="background-image:url('Images/banner-transparente.jpg'); border: solid 1px green">
                <img src="Images/logo-trt-home.png" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It works perfectly!

[1] https://jsfiddle.net/bwth52ft/

Answer (score 0):

I would make the first image a background image. Putting position: absolute on the logo is going to make it ignore its container.

Not completely done, but closer: http://jsfiddle.net/s116Ld99/7/

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://files.intersu.webnode.pt/200000002-a2450a33fe/bannerB[1].jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100% auto; border:solid 1px green">
    <img src="https://eloconcursos.com.br/imagem/59954926655ae736857b696.73701051.jpg/167/200/4:3" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: The width of image's parent is fixed which gets from the image. When you resize the window, it does not changed so the image is big in small screen.

You can add `width`(percent) to the image container. It's better to do this by css media query in certain width.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/s116Ld99/9/)

```
 <div style=" width:20%;position: absolute; top: 20%; border:solid 1px yellow">
                    <img src="https://eloconcursos.com.br/imagem/59954926655ae736857b696.73701051.jpg/167/200/4:3" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
```